# How to return the IEnumerable<T> Value using Datable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

I am trying to do return dataTable value from IEnumerable Type
Anyone can help me For if i will pass any type for IEnumerable it will return that value

```
IEnumerable<T> enrichment = null;
var dataTable = new DataTable();

using (ReconContext context = new ReconContext())
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + DestinationTable + "  WHERE LoadId =" + ExternalLoadId;

    using (SqlDataAdapter adapater = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
    {
        adapater.Fill(dataTable);
    }
}
return enrichment;
```

Comment: It's not clear at all what `enrichment` is for or how it relates to the `DataTable`.

Comment: It's also not clear what this has to do with `Linq-To-Entities` or what type `T` is. Do you want a generic method that converts a `DataTable` to `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is a custom class? Then there are already available approaches using reflection like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662318/how-to-convert-datatable-to-listt-using-reflections).

Comment: That's a SQL Injection attack waiting to happen. I wonder, what will happen if I pass ` 2 OR 1=1--` as a value to `ExternalLoadId`

Comment: Why do you use a DataTable and SqlDataAdapter when you already have an EF Context? Why don't you use [SqlQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx) method?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you do not need to use generic definition unless you really need to. For general circumstances you can easily use DataRow like below;

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> enrichment = null;
var dataTable = new DataTable();
using (ReconContext context = new ReconContext())
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + DestinationTable + "  WHERE LoadId =" + ExternalLoadId;

    using (SqlDataAdapter adapater = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
    {
        adapater.Fill(dataTable);
    }
}

enrichment = dataTable.AsEnumerable();
return enrichment;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ya this is right but if my function like this the      public IEnumerable<T> GeEnrichmendataByTableNameAndLoadId<T>(string DestinationTable, int ExternalLoadId)
        { }

Comment: So, for this circumstance your SqlDataAdapter should fill datatable with type of T if not you should create a method which converts your data table to strongly type which type of T.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework already allows you to execute raw SQL queries and map their results to entities with [SqlQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx). You don't need to use raw ADO.NET. You could just write:

```
public IEnumerable<T> LoadSomeLoads<T>(string table,int loadId)
{
    using (ReconContext context = new ReconContext())
    {
       var sq;="SELECT * FROM "+ table+ "  WHERE LoadId = @p0";
       var results= context.SqlQuery<T>(sql,loadId)
                           .ToArray();
    }
}
```

You should validate the `table` parameter to ensure it's an allowed table name, otherwise someone could query tables he has no authorization to, or simply browse for data by forcing the table name.

You avoid catastrophic injection attacks by using parameters but that doesn't prevent unauthorized disclosure if someone can force a query to an inappropriate table.

I suspect though that you should be looking to table-per-type inheritance. It sounds like you want to load different classes from different tables, where at least one property (LoadId) is common.

With [Table-per-Type](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt) EF maps different types of an inheritance hierarchy to different tables and selects the correct table based on the mapping configuration.

Assuming, eg that you have the following classes:

```
public abstract class LoadTypeBase
{
    public int LoadId { get; set; }
    ...
}

[Table("LoadTableA")]
public class LoadTypeA : LoadTypeBase
{
    ...
}


[Table("LoadTableB")]
public class LoadTypeA : LoadTypeBase
{
    ...
}
```

and this context

```
public class ReconContext: DbContext
{
    ...
    public DbSet<LoadTypeBase> Loads { get; set; }
}
```

You could query for all load types with a specific LoadId with :

```
var query = from someLoad in context.Loads
            where someLoad.LoadId = loadId
            select someLoad;
```

You can restrict results to a specific type with `OfType<T>()`

```
var query = from someLoad in context.Loads.OfType<LoadTypeB>()
            where someLoad.LoadId = loadId
            select someLoad;
```

Comment: I triyed this one i am getting list of  blank datatable not getting rows do you have solution for how willl get the rows

Comment: My code doesn't have any data tables or rows. What did you actually try? Why are you trying to extract data rows when you are already using an ORM ?

Comment: Hey can you see your first answer   context.SqlQuery<T> ? that i said you

Comment: Please post what you actually tried and what was the actual result in the question. My answer doesn't use DataRow or DataTable objects anywhere, it doesn't need them. The first query will map to anything that has the same *property* names as the query results.

Comment: Ok leave it using this LoadSomeLoads function  how i will return the rows from that table ? what i need to pass LoadSomeLoads  function ?

Comment: I'm still waiting for details and explanations. What rows are you talking about? Where is the *actual code* that you tried? Did you use a proper class or `DataRow`? Why `DataRow` when EF already returns the actual class? Why do you want to use `DataRow` when you already use Entity Framework?

Answer (score -1):

Ya this is right but if my function will like this the  so how i can use datarow 
i want to out put which i will pass Type that will be retun

```
 public IEnumerable<T> GeEnrichmendataByTableNameAndLoadId<T>(stringDestinationTable, int ExternalLoadId)
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Please delete.

Comment: Please edit the original question if you want to provide additional information. Also explain the reason you try to execute raw SQL when you already use Entity Framework