# Dynamically subscribe to events in a method?

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates

### Introduction

In my current WPF project I quite regularly  had to convert `DataTables` into Lists of model classes, like this:

```
public void CreateExmapleModeList()
{
    ExampleModels = new List<ExampleModel>();
    foreach (DataRow row in tbl)
    {
        ExampleModel example = new ExampleModel
        {
            Name = row["Name"].ToString(),
            Tag = row["Tag"].ToString(),
            Value = double.Parse(row["Value"].ToString()),
            // [...]

        };
        ExampleModels.Add(example);
        example.PropertyChanged += ExampleModel_PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

assinging dozens of properties for dozens of lists is quite annoying, so I googled a little and found [this quite handy answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12662388/7696590) on StackOverflow to assign properties dynamically, which cut down creating new lists to this:

```
ExampleModels = ListConverter.ConvertToList<ExampleModel>(tbl);
```

### Problem

Now after refactoring my code I didn't know how to subscribe my custom PropertyChanged-Event to the PropertyChanged-Event of my model, so I simply iterated through the whole list again:

```
foreach (ExampleModel exmp in ExampleModels)
{
    example.PropertyChanged += ExampleModel_PropertyChanged;
}
```

PropertyChanged:

```
public void ExampleModel_Propertychanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}
```

### Question

I would much rather subscribe to the PropertyChanged-Event when creating the list rather then redundantly iterate a second time through the whole list.

Since there are quite a few Models, which have custom PropertyChanged-Events I need to subscribe them dynamically.

**Is there a way simular to the RelayCommand for example:**

```
public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
{
    m_execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
    m_canExecute = canExecute;

}
```

**to tell my ContVertToList-Method which event it has to subscirbe
like:**

```
ExampleModels = ListConverter.ConvertToList<ExampleModel>(tbl, ExampleModel_Propertychanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e));
```

**and in `ConvertToList` something like this:**

```
public static List<T> ConvertToList<T>(DataTable dt, CustomPropertyChanged<S, E>) where T : TemplateModel

 // [...]
 objT.PropertyChanged = CustomPropertyChanged;
 return onjT;
 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass a `PropertyChangedEventHandler` to your method and hook it up using the `+=` syntax:

```
public static List<T> ConvertToList<T>(DataTable dt, PropertyChangedEventHandler eventHandler) where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //...
    objT.PropertyChanged += eventHandler;
}
```

Usage:

```
var list = ConvertToList<YourType>(dataTable, ExampleModel_Propertychanged);
...
private void ExampleModel_Propertychanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: holy moly. This looks so easy, but i guess I would have never figured it out on my own. Thank you very much.